# Custom picker renderer ios crash on done button clicked

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

I want to create a picker with two wheels on Xamarin Forms. I made it easy on Android but on iOS I'm in trouble.

The picker crash when I tapped on the "Done" button or when it loses focus.

To create my picker I've just made a renderer which inherits from PickerRenderer, then I've created a PickerModel with 2 tabs for two wheels.
After that, I set the model to the picker in the OnElementChanged.

But the app crash when I want to close the picker, what I've missed?

**PS : I'v already tried Control.ResigneFirstResponder or
 Control.Unfocus() but it always thrown an InvalidCastException**

```cs
//There is my PickerModel
public partial class PickerModel : UIPickerViewModel
        {
            private int[] hours = Enumerable.Range(0, 1001).ToArray();
            private int[] minutes = Enumerable.Range(0, 60).ToArray();

            public override nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView pickerView)
            {
                return 2;
            }

            public override nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
            {
                switch (component)
                {
                    case 0: return hours.Length;
                    case 1: return minutes.Length;
                    default: break;
                }
                return 0;
            }

            public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
            {
                // Returns
                switch (component)
                {
                    case 0: return hours[row].ToString();
                    case 1: return minutes[row].ToString();
                    default: break;
                }
                return null;
            }

            public override nfloat GetComponentWidth(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
            {
                switch (component)
                {
                    case 0: return 100.0f;
                    case 1: return 100.0f;
                    case 2: return 100.0f;
                    default: break;
                }

                return 0;
            }

            public override nfloat GetRowHeight(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
            {
                return 40f;
            }

        }



//and this is OnElementChanged
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            picker = Element;
            UITextField textField = Control;
            UIPickerView pickerView = textField.InputView as UIPickerView;


            pickerView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
            pickerView.Model = new PickerModel();

            hours = ((CustomTimeSpanPicker)Element).Hours;
            minutes = ((CustomTimeSpanPicker)Element).Minutes;

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging and checking if something is null or not? I do not see null checks also I have a feeling you are not casting the controls the right way!!

Comment: the only error I had is InvalidCastException when I use Control. I never saw a null value. Currently I'm work on it, I comeback if I find the soluce.

Thank for your answer

Comment: Yeah exactly what I am saying you are not casting the control in the correct way!